# Polygon clip path animate with parallax

Tags: css, cross-browser, polygon, parallax, css-shapes

http://jsfiddle.net/kirstendodd/SsnC4/12/

```
data-0-top="
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 74% 0%, 75% 0%, 21% 100%); 
 -moz-clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 74% 0%, 75% 0%, 21% 100%); 
 clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 74% 0%, 75% 0%, 21% 100%);"
data--200-top=" 
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(-50% 100%, 0% 0%, 150% 0%, 100% 100%); 
 -moz-clip-path: polygon(-50% 100%, 0% 0%, 150% 0%, 100% 100%); 
 clip-path: polygon(-50% 100%, 0% 0%, 150% 0%, 100% 100%);
```

Okay basically I am working on a skrollr parallax site and the designer wants an animated mask  effect. Which if you are using chrome or safari you can see working in the above jsfiddle.  My question is, does anyone know of a way to do this that will have better browser support?  I need it to be able to work within skrollr, be responsive to the height of the window, be on html elements not just images, AND work in at least ie10, firefox, chrome, and Safari.  Is this possible?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be doable with inline SVG for clipping. I remember someone has already done this, but I can't find it right now.